# Updating data of users authenticated via OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I have a Rails app using the Omni-Auth GitHub gem. User account creation and signin via GitHub works flawlessly!

Here's my User model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_github_uid(auth["uid"]) || create_from_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.github_uid = auth["uid"]
      user.github_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
      user.username = auth["info"]["nickname"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      user.full_name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.gravatar_id = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gravatar_id"]
      user.blog_url = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["blog"]
      user.company = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["company"]
      user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]
      user.hireable = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["hireable"]
      user.bio = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["bio"]
    end
  end
```

But sometimes users change their bio or company or wether or not they want to be hired, so I rather than having to delete old accounts, I figured it would be nice if it updated for them in a timely fashion after they updated their account.

**What's the best practice for doing this and how can I use my existing OmniAuth code to update the user's information?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = find_by_github_uid(auth["uid"]) || User.new
    user.assign_from_omniauth(auth).save!
  end

  def assign_from_omniauth(auth)
      self.github_uid ||= auth["uid"]
      self.github_token ||= auth["credentials"]["token"]
      self.username ||= auth["info"]["nickname"]
      self.email ||= auth["info"]["email"]
      self.full_name = auth["info"]["name"]
      self.gravatar_id = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gravatar_id"]
      self.blog_url = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["blog"]
      self.company = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["company"]
      self.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]
      self.hireable = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["hireable"]
      self.bio = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["bio"]
  end
```

Comment: Then how can I `PUT` to this assign_from_omniauth method via AJAX if this method is in my model?

Comment: When I try this with omniauth-facebook, I get an error message about not being able to save an array. It seems like it's just trying to save the last value. Did you have any luck with this?